# How to correctly add View value in Module via Controller?

Tags: javascript, oop, model-view-controller, ecmascript-6

Actually the whole question in the title, I have a button written in HTML,  let's say this is my View, which returns a number:

```
export class View {

    addItem() {
        let plus = document.querySelector('.plus');
        plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let num = document.querySelector('.count').innerHTML;
            return num;
        })
    }
}
```

Here is my Module with addNum function, which actually should add a number to the array:

```
export class Module {
    constructor() {
        this.num = [];
    }


    addNum(num){
        this.num.push(num);
    }

}
```

Heres the Controller:

```
class Controller {
    constructor(view, module){
        this.view = view;
this.module = module;
    }

    getNum(){
        this.cart.addNum(this.view.addItem());

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the getNum controller function, it works instantly, how can I wait for an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be naturally handled with RxJS observables. They are well-suited for such purposes, i.e. building reactive UIs and extensively used in Angular.

An observable is basically a stream of values that can be transformed and in the end, subscribed. It has a lot in common with promises which were suggested in another answer, but an observable results in a sequence of values, while a promise results in one value.

RxJS contains extensive functionality, including the support for DOM events. RxJS `fromEvent` (see [a short tutorial](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html)) replaces `addEventListener` and creates a stream of click events that can be mapped to another value (form input value):

```
addItem() {
  let plus = document.querySelector('.plus');

  return Observable.fromEvent(plus, 'click')
  .map((event) => {
    return document.querySelector('.count').innerHTML;
  });
}
```

An observable is subscribed in place where values should be received:

```
getNum(){
  this.numSubscription = this.view.addItem().subscribe(num => {
    this.module.addNum(num);
  });
}
```

A stream of values can be stopped by unsubscribing from an observable, `this.numSubscription.unsubscribe()`. This will internally trigger `removeEventListener`.

Here's [a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/40UJMTmW3jcTumNG0it6?p=preview).